# Exclude records when a DisposalState is set to "Disposed-off" from "Pending" in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Main_Cause_List]
WHERE DisposalState is 'Disposed-off';
```

I want to to hide those rows whose case status is changed to "Pending" from case status "Disposed-off". As one case is Disposed-off, then I no need to show that case that in the pending case list.

Basically I will make two lists: (1) for pending case list and (2) for disposed-off list.

For example: once a case fixed for a date=08-05-2021 at that time its DisposalStatus was Pending but in the same date the same Disposed-off.

So when I make BarType Chart then on the same it show me that case in pending list too...how to avoid that case which has been disposed-off...

[image]

Comment: How is this C# related? It's not really clear what you are asking.  To me, it seems like a simple `where` clause is all you need?

Comment: the image is self-explanatory sir ...

Comment: @TimothyG. sir once a case fixed for a date=08-05-2021 at that time its DisposalStatus was Pending but in the same date the same Disposed-off .... So when i make BarType Chart then on the same it show me that case in pending list too...how to avoid that case which has been disposed-off...

Comment: @TimothyG. Sir check the image, Check the ane above for each Highlighted row.

Comment: Do you want to show *all* rows unless they have `Dispossed-off` for the same `CaseNo` (? or another column?) or do you want to just show a single row with each `CaseNo`?

Comment: @charlieface sir exactly sir

Comment: For the same CaseNo....once a case disposed off then i want to hide all its Pending cases record for that Case No...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to remove from your result all `CaseNo` for which there is at least one row with `DisposalState = 'Dispossed-off'`. You can use a windowed conditional `COUNT` for this.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DisposalState = 'Dispossed-off' THEN 1 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY CaseNo) CountDisposed
    FROM [Main_Cause_List]
) m
WHERE CountDisposed = 0;
```

Comment: Yes it is working.....But Now how we will count them on the basis of NextDate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, where does NextDate come into the logic?